# Increase chat room font size for tablet viewing

Tags: feature-request, chat, font-size

The font size in chat rooms seems to be much smaller than the rest of the stackoverflow site.  Please increase it to be more consistent and easier to read.  Or is there a reason it is smaller?

**[EDIT]**

As you can see from the comments, the impetus for asking this question is browser specific.  Thanks for those comments!  I'll address that problem elsewhwere :).  However, I still think it makes sense to increase the font size of chat rooms to match that of the rest of the site.  Is there a reason chat is smaller?

Comment: The chat font size is 12px, whereas the main site post font size is 14px... Don't see why it's a problem, though (how about zooming in your browser?).

Comment: `Ctrl` + `+` seems to work fine for me?

Comment: Perhaps this is simply a browser specific problem.  On iPad, there is no Ctrl-+.  And zooming doesn't seem to work in the chat rooms (it does everywhere else I've tried in SO).

Comment: Ah, okay. That's a different matter indeed. I know of no way to do this on the iPad

Comment: Hold the iPad closer to your face?

Comment: Hmm, no repro in IE6

Comment: @Won't you mean no repro in your Surface tablet running Windows 8 and a VM with Windows XP and IE6 on it?

Comment: @Pekka: No, I actually meant, "ha hah!  Nyah!"

Comment: @Won't yeah, that would have been my second guess. :P